# Update doors attributes by dxl script giving input csv file

Tags: ibm-doors

Update doors attributes by dxl script giving input csv file. 
I want to take values from csv file and want to update doors attribute  with same using dxl script

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I know, there is no such feature. You will have to write that as DXL script which seems to be absolutely possible. You know, there are consultants who do that for a living and who could implement that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Doors can already do that. File->import->spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSV import and choose the option "Update Existing", provide the primary key.

Refer "Using Rational DOORS" @ "http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27041281"